# Preventing shifting active windows to the left on reconnection to Windows 10 sessions with Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-10, macos, remote-desktop

I use Remote Desktop on a MacBook Pro to connect to my Windows 10 machines. I'm using two external monitors for the Remote Desktop sessions.

Every time I restart my connection to the Windows machines (that is, I'm connecting to an existing Windows session, not logging in from scratch), my active Windows apps' windows are shifted to the left side of the screen, which covers up my Windows Desktop icons, which are on the left side of the screen. And then I have to move all the apps' windows to the right to expose the icons.

I would like this to stop happening, either by:

- Not having my apps' windows get shifted at all when I reconnect with Remote Desktop.
- Having the shifting done to the right, so my Desktop icons don't get obscured.

Are there any settings to so?

(Of course, I would expect moving the icons to the right side of the screen would avoid this, but I'm hoping there's a simple registry change to fix this.)

Comment: I've never seen that happen in 10 years or more of regularly RDC'ing into Win from Mac. What versions of everything - macOS, Win OS, RDC? What are your RDC settings on the Mac, especially your RDC 'Display' tab? Windows, of course, is notorious for moving things around if the display resolution changes, so that would be first thing to check.

Comment: MacOs Catalina 10.15.7. Remote Desktop 10.5.0. Display settings: Resolution - "Default for this Display" with "Start session in full screen" and "Fit session to window" checked. Color quality = "High (32 bit)" with no optimization for Retina displays and no updating the session resolution on resize. I am using a wide-screen monitor 3440x1440.

Comment: Yes, that might be the issue - unless the remote machine has exactly the same screen  resolution, you're resetting the Windows desktop & Windows is making up its own mind where everything ought to belong. Use the same resolution as the remote screen. Fullscreen & Fit to window shouldn't affect it.